# Wordpress Help: How to remove author and tags from P2 theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have recently installed the P2 Theme on my site: http://news.nocamels.com/
and I want to know How to remove author and tags from P2 theme?

Thanks!

Comment: do you expect that everybody knows the 'p2' theme? easy way out; hide it with css.

Comment: that's the reason I added a link...

Answer (score 1):

There is a step by step guide is given [link](http://perfectwebtutorials.com/2011/how-to-remove-is-proudly-powered-by-wordpress-in-footer/) here.
Make sure to read the comments below but this will get you sorted :

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not post link-only answers; if you could edit an excerpt of the article into your answer, your answer will remain useful when the link dies.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find `<span class="tags">` inside of `<span class="meta">` and `get_the_tags()` in your loop.php file. I see that you have hidden it as @janw suggested. If you truly want to remove it, you will have to get rid of the calls in your PHP.